# one error in my programm to get the primfactor from a primnumber

Tags: haskell

Through the part of program under the imaginary line all the primfactors from a primnumber is calculated and outputed. The Part of program over the imaginary line gets  out the primnumber from 2 to infinity.

the error occured in the following line

```
   |npf m primnumber == True = head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])
```

The warning was shown as:

```
E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:17:33: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[[Int]]' with actual type `Int'
    * In the first argument of `(++)', namely `head primnumber'
      In the expression:
        head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber) : [])
      In an equation for `primfactor':
          primfactor m
            | npf m primnumber == True
            = head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber) : [])
   |
17 |     |npf m primnumber == True = head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])

   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:17:33: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'
      Expected type: [Int]
        Actual type: [[Int]]
    * In the expression:
        head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber) : [])
      In an equation for `primfactor':
          primfactor m
            | npf m primnumber == True
            = head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber) : [])
   |
17 |     |npf m primnumber == True = head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])

   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Finished in 2.8s]
```

I have been checking the expressions in the line for many times. But I can't get the reason.

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

--the second primnumer Function from leture
primnumber = 2: [n| n<-[3..], prim n primnumber]
prim n (p:xs) 
    |p*p > n = True
    |n `mod` p == 0 = False
    |otherwise = prim n xs

-------------------------------------------------------

primfactor :: Int -> [Int]
primfactor m 
    |npf m primnumber == True = head primnumber ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])

npf n (x:xs)
    |n `mod` x == 0 = True
    |otherwise = npf n xs
```

after correction

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

--the second primnumer Function from leture

primnumber = 2: [n| n<-[3..], prim n primnumber]
prim n (p:xs) 
    |p*p > n = True
    |n `mod` p == 0 = False
    |otherwise = prim n xs

-------------------------------------------------------
npf :: Integer->[Integer]->Integer
npf n (x:xs)
    |n `mod` x == 0 = x 
    |n `mod` x == 1 = 1
    |otherwise = npf n xs 

primfactor :: Integer -> [Integer]
primfactor 1 = []
primfactor m = [npf m primnumber] ++ ((primfactor (m `div` (npf m primnumber)):[])
```

the error

```
E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:23:83: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
23 | primfactor m = [npf m primnumber] ++ ((primfactor (m `div` (npf m primnumber)):[])
   |                                                                                   ^
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: runhaskell "E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs"]
[dir: E:\Haskell]
[path: C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;E:\8.6.3\lib\extralibs\bin;E:\8.6.3\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\matlab\bin;E:\8.6.3\mingw\bin;C:\Users\HuFengXiang\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\HuFengXiang\AppData\Roaming\local\bin]
```

Comment: Add more explicit type signatures, and use `Integer` instead of `Int` (since eventually your prime numbers will grow beyond what an `Int` can hold). However, the problem is that you are calling `primfactor` with a list `(m/head primnumber):[]`, not an `Int`.

Comment: A question which I hope will help you find one of your many bugs: for what inputs do you expect `npf` to return something other than `True`? Does GHC agree?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I have corrected the program after your tipp. But one error appeared still in the program i have corrected...

Comment: @Daniel Wagner Could u give me some other tipps ?

Answer (score 2):

```
primnumber :: [Int]     -- a list of numbers
head primnumber :: Int  -- a single number
(++) :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

`head primnumber` cannot be first (left) argument of operator `(++)`, because it is of the wrong type: the operator expects a list (in this case, `[Int]`), but you're providing an `Int`.

It is not entirely clear from your code what it's supposed to be doing in the first place, so I can't tell you how to fix it exactly. If you meant to "prepend" `head primfactor` to the list, then you could wrap it in a list like this:

```
[head primnumber] ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])
```

Or, better yet, use the `(:)` constructor directly:

```
(head primnumber) : (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])
```

If you wanted to do something else, please specify what it was.

Comment: `
primfactor :: Integer -> [Integer]
primfactor 1 = []
primfactor m 
    |npf m primnumber == True = [head primnumber] ++ (primfactor (m / head primnumber):[])
npf n (x:xs)
    |n `mod` x == 0 = True
    |otherwise = npf n xs `                                                                                               I have corrected the line. But one error exists still...I don't see why. I have all day for that...mgd @Fyodor Soikin

Comment: There's also the `(/)` vs `div` error. And then there's a bunch of logical errors that type-checking won't/can't catch...

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin There is still one error I can't take away... plz give me some advices ...

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis at the very end